# PermissionsEX is not working Minecraft server plugin

Tags: plugins, server, minecraft

My PermissionsEX was working perfectly fine until I started adding permissions
I am almost sure the problem is in the permissions.yml file

Here is the code:

```
groups:
  default:
    options:
      default: true
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sethome
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.warp.*
  donator:
    options:
      prefix: '&2Donator: '
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sethome
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.warp.*
    - essentials.pay

  Member:
    options:
      prefix: '&aMember '
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sethome.multiple.member
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.warp.*
    - essentials.kits.member
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.joinfullserver
    - essentials.enderchest
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.pay
  ridder:
    options:
      prefix: '&7&lRidder '
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sethome.multiple.ridder
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.warp.*
    - essentials.kits.member
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.joinfullserver
    - essentials.enderchest
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.kits.ridder
    - essentials.pay


  SlotGraaf:
    options:
      prefix: '&5&l&nSlotgraaf '
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sethome.multiple.slotgraaf
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.warp.*
    - essentials.kits.member
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.joinfullserver
    - essentials.enderchest
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.kits.ridder
    - essentials.kits.slotgraaf
    - essentials.nick
    - essentials.back
    - essentials.pay

  Prins:
 options:
      prefix: '&5&l&nPrins '
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sethome.multiple.prins
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.warp.*
    - essentials.kits.member
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.joinfullserver
    - essentials.enderchest
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.kits.ridder
    - essentials.kits.slotgraaf
    - essentials.nick
    - essentials.back
    - essentials.chat.color
    - essentials.kits.rp
    - essentials.pay
  Koning:
    options:
      prefix: '&e&l&nKoning '
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sethome.multiple.koning
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.warp.*
    - essentials.kits.member
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.joinfullserver
    - essentials.enderchest
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.kits.ridder
    - essentials.kits.slotgraaf
    - essentials.nick
    - essentials.back
    - essentials.chat.color
    - essentials.kits.rp
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.feed
    - essentials.kits.koning
  Owner:
    options:
      prefix: '&e&l&nKoning '
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sethome
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.warp.*
    - essentials.kits.member
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.joinfullserver
    - essentials.enderchest
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.kits.ridder
    - essentials.kits.slotgraaf
    - essentials.nick
    - essentials.back
    - essentials.chat.color
    - essentials.kits.rp
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.heal
    - essentials.kits.koning
    - essentials.feed
    - essentials.fly


  admin:
    permissions:
   - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.seen.banreason
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sethome
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.warp.*
schema-version: 1
users:
  5d0cd39d-a885-4c63-b2ad-f988da45f666:
    group:
    - admin
    options:
      name: de_hongerlijder
  8941157d-714b-41cb-adf4-9acf5d38fe98:
    group:
    - Koning
    options:
      name: mvelasco3
```

Comment: Can you describe problem occured? Some logs, errors, stack traces. And please, provide raw permissions.yml because I think person edited your post may losed some indents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Yaml syntax is incorrect. While copy and pasting it at [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), the following syntax error ocurred

> ERROR:
>
> while parsing a block mapping
>     in "", line 2, column 5:
>           groups:
>           ^
>
> expected , but found ''
>     in "", line 119, column 6:
>            options:

What that means is that your spacing is incorrect. For a normal syntax, you should do the following:

```
groups:
 default:
  options:
   default: true
  permissions:
  - essentials.spawn
```

Notice the spacings. If I were to change them for asterisks, just for the visuals, they'd be like this:

```
groups:
*default:
**options:
***default: true
**permissions:
**- essentials.spawn
(...)
```

But if we look at your syntax, it's wrong in some places. Take a look at lines:

---

**118**:

```
  Prins:
 options:
      prefix: '&5&l&nPrins '
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
```

It should be:

```
  Prins:
   options:
    prefix: '&5&l&nPrins '
   permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
```

---

**217**:

```
 admin:
    permissions:
   - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
```

And it should be

```
 admin:
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - modifyworld.*
```